# How to set NativeBase Toast width to 100%?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using NativeBase toast but I want to know how can I set the width of toast to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom theme definitions for NativeBase and add it to your NativeBaseProvider.

More information here on NativeBase [themeing](https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-theme).

```
<NativeBaseProvider theme={YourCustomTheme}>
```

Make sure to define your Toast component inside your custom theme. Load the Dimensions library from 'react-native' and use it to define the width.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const NBCustomTheme = {
  components: {
    Toast: {
      baseStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width
      }
    }
  }
}
export default NBCustomTheme;
```